# 400 error "Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request." in google scripts api, no issues until changing to different google account

Tags: javascript, api, request, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I have an extremely basic API made in google scripts, that I have linked to a spreadsheet. I originally made it on my home google account and everything was working fine, I had no errors, I made it on my PC at home and ran into no errors, but when I tested it on my laptop I couldn't access it. The issue was I made it on my home google account but my school email account was made so it couldn't access files or anything outside of my school system so I just copy and pasted all my code into a google script on my school account and did the same for the spreadsheet as it is for a school project. When I just input the api link like normal it works fine, however now whenever put in a query google returns "400. That’s an error. Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know." This wasn't an issue before on the API I made on my home email, and all I did was copy and paste the code nothing changed, here is the code.

```
function  doGet(request){
  var query = request.parameter.q
  var parameters = 6;
  var sheetname = "Sheet1";
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('key'));
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetname)
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var rows = [];
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastrow,parameters);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var data
  var data_return
  for(var row in values){
    rows.push([]);
    for(var col in values[row]){
      rows[row].push(values[row][col]);
    }
  }
  if(query != null){
  if(query.includes('data[')){
    data = query.replace("data[", "");
    data = data.replace("]", "")
    data_return = "data sent: " + data
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A17').setValue(data);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({data_return})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
  else{
    var rowstoreturn = rows.filter(a => a[0] == query)
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({rowstoreturn})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }}
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({rows})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

function setup() {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

The link to the api I set up with my home email is
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwvPPynR9FAkUgMejjtQE9Rqo0ayaJPbmFoaaomkjeZobgJN_x3smasjHdeSfOTkvMO/exec

I would sent the link I also made on my school account but I can't as I can only make files accessible to people in my school system. To make a query it's like a normal API right after EXEC you just put ?q= and then whatever query you want. I can't seem to find the issue is there any fix to this? Thanks! If there is anything else I need to provide please let me know.

Comment: What have you set `execute the app as` to?